# http://localhost:8100/ Blank after I added login state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, react-hooks

I attempted to add login authentication to my app. Now when I launch the app using ionic serve the http://localhost:8100/ is blank, however when I add /login it takes me to the login page. How do I automatically redirect the launch page to /login. I'm quite new to React and Ionic so my understanding of states is quite limited

Source code

```
App.tsx

import { IonApp } from '@ionic/react';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react'

import { IonReactRouter } from '@ionic/react-router';

/* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
import '@ionic/react/css/core.css';

/* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
import '@ionic/react/css/normalize.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/structure.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/typography.css';

/* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */
import '@ionic/react/css/padding.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/float-elements.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/text-alignment.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/text-transformation.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/flex-utils.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/display.css';

/* Theme variables */
import './theme/variables.css';
import { SignInTabs } from './components/Tabs/MainTabs';
import { SignOutTabs } from './components/Tabs/SignedOut';
import { useContext, useState } from 'react';

interface IUserManager {
  setIsLoggedIn: Function;
}

const user: IUserManager = {
  setIsLoggedIn: () => {}
}

export const UserContext = React.createContext<IUserManager>(user);

const IonicApp: React.FC = () => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const user = useContext(UserContext);

  user.setIsLoggedIn = setIsLoggedIn;
  let route = (<Route path="/" component={SignOutTabs} />);

  if (isLoggedIn) {
    route = (<Route path="/" component={SignInTabs}  />)
  } 

  return(
    <IonApp>
      <IonReactRouter>
        {route}
      </IonReactRouter>
    </IonApp>
  )

}

const App: React.FC = () => (
  <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
    <IonicApp />
  </UserContext.Provider>

);

export default App;
```

```
import { IonButton, IonCol, IonContent, IonGrid, IonPage, IonRow } from "@ionic/react"
import { UserContext } from "../../App";
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledGrid = styled(IonGrid)`
    margin-top: 16em;
`;

const StyledRow = styled(IonRow)`
    text-align: center;
`;

const StyledButton = styled(IonButton)`
    --background: black;
    border-radius: 50px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 210px;
`;

const StyledCol  = styled(IonCol)`
    margin-top: 14em
`;

const StyledSignUp  = styled(IonCol)`

`;

export const LoginComponent: React.FC = () => {

    const user = useContext(UserContext);

    const loginClick = () => {
            user.setIsLoggedIn(true);
    }
    

    return(
        <IonPage>
            <IonContent fullscreen>
                <StyledGrid>
                    <StyledRow>
                        <IonCol>
                            <img src="assets/icon/logosqr.png" alt="firstbase logo" height="100"/>
                        </IonCol>
                        <StyledCol size="12">
                            <span> Create a new account  </span>    
                        </StyledCol>
                        <StyledSignUp size="12">
                            <StyledButton onClick={loginClick}>
                                <span> Log in with Phone Number </span>
                            </StyledButton>
                        </StyledSignUp>
                        <StyledSignUp size="12">
                            <StyledButton onClick={loginClick}>
                                <span> Log in with Facebook </span>
                            </StyledButton>
                        </StyledSignUp>
                    </StyledRow>
                </StyledGrid>
            </IonContent>
        </IonPage>
    )
}
```

Comment: Neither `SignOutTabs` or `SignInTabs` are defined. Have you check the console for errors?

Comment: @Phil Can you have a look again please.